# Postgresql filter in relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table "*Post*":

| id | active |
| --- | --- |
| 382857 | true |
| 382851 | true |
| 383015 | true |
| 382906 | true |
| 382909 | true |

Table "*PosTags*":

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 382857 | 480 |
| 382857 | 953 |
| 382857 | 9230 |
| 382857 | 9232 |
| 382857 | 56677 |
| 382857 | 107901 |

The first table stores posts, while the second one stores postags for each post. I need to gather information regarding posts and tags and I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM posts
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_tags WHERE tag_id = 55723)
LIMIT 8
```

Problem is that this query won't retrieve posts that have no postags.

Can you help me fixing this query?

Comment: Can you please attach output of `EXPLAIN` and DDL you've used to create mentioned tables?

Comment: QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=460.44..460.90 rows=8 width=5)
  ->  Seq Scan on pgvk_material  (cost=460.44..11135.67 rows=187409 width=5)
        Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Index Scan using fki_pgvk_material_tag_id_fkey on pgvk_material_tag  (cost=0.43..460.13 rows=124 width=4)
                Index Cond: (tag_id = 55723)

Comment: create table posts
(
    id          bigserial
        primary key,
    .....
);

create table post_tags
(
    post_id bigint not null
        constraint post_tags_post_id_foreign
            references posts
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    tag_id  bigint not null
        constraint post_tags_tag_id_foreign
            references tags
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    primary key (post_id, tag_id)
);

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT posts.id,
       posts.active
FROM      posts
LEFT JOIN posttags
       ON posts.id = posttags.post_id
      AND posttags.tag_id = 9230
WHERE posttags.post_id IS NULL
```

Basically it looks for the posts which have the specific `tag_id` you don't want and excludes them from the match of the `posts` table using a `LEFT JOIN`.

If you have more than one tag you want to exclude, it is sufficient to change the second part of the JOIN condition into the following:

```
AND posttags.tag_id IN [9230, ...]
```

SQL Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ddd0239246e3bda0bb71f658bbf45ed1).

Comment: exelent solution

Comment: If this answer has helped you, consider ticking it as the solution of your post. @Brain2xml